# Formatar data Javascript, achar dia da semana?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte problema.

Tenho um data picker que me da o valor da data assim : dd-mm-aaa (13-05-2016)

Mas preciso verificar que dia da semana é ex: Hoje é sexta. 
O problema que não consigo verificar com esse formato.

Eu teria que pegar o valor do campo e mudar ele para usar New Date() e getDay()
para verificar. 
Agora como faço isso ?

Ou tenho como verificar com esse formato mesmo ?

Ou como usar o método `toLocaleDateString`

Obs preciso que seja em javascript não Jquery, estou aprendendo JS.

Abraços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minha resposta para o problema.

```
var str = campo.value,
    parts = str.split('-'),
    year = parseInt(parts[2], 10),
    month = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,
    day = parseInt(parts[0], 10),
    date = new Date(year, month, day),
    dia = date.getDay();

if (dia == "6") {
    alert("Sábado ");
}
if (dia == "0") {
    alert(" Domingo");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var from = $("#datepicker").val().split("-"); //(15-05-2016)
var f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
```

Créditos:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date

Comment: Ajustei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado, funciona bem. Pena que é com Jquery. 
Já consegui fazer com js puro. 

Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Ah sim, o jQuery é só pra selecionar o elemento, mas o foco é splitar a sua data pelo '-' e utilizar os parâmetros na ordem correta do date.